# Flutter - Get LatLong from json

Tags: json, flutter, dart, latitude-longitude

```
      factory FieldModel.fromJson(String fieldId, Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) =>
      FieldModel(
        fieldId: fieldId,
        ownerId: json['ownerId'],
        name: json['name'],
        imageUrl: json['imageUrl'],

        ///how to extract this, its a LatLng class from "google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/src/types/location.dart"
        latLng: json['latLng'],
        description: json['description'],
        charges: json['charges'],
        timeSlots: json['timeSlots'],
        availability: json['availability'],
      );
```

Error: "type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of LatLng."

Comment: You have to create a LatLng from your json,

atLng: LatLng(json['latLng']['lat'], json['latLng']['lng'] ) ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your json looks like this,

```json
... 
"latLng": {"lat": 1234.121, "lng": 958.1232}
...
```

You will have to use your latLng value to create a LatLng object,

```dart
latLng: LatLng(json['latLng']['lat'], json['latLng']['lng']),
```

Comment: In my case it was json['latLng']['geopoint'].latitude,  json['latLng']['geopoint'].longitude.